# WPF implementing a rubberband type selection within a listbox

Tags: listbox, selection, hittest, rubber-band

I'm trying to allow rubberband or lasso type selection of the items in the `Listbox` that the user wants selected.  My `Listbox` is in a grid and to the grid I added a control that draws a rectangle over the area I want to select.  I've tried hit testing the `Listbox` items to see if they fall within the rectangle but they all seem to return that they don't.  When looking at the `VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds` for those items (like I do for the rectangle to get it's X,Y) it always returns X,Y as 0,0 for each of the items.  What am I doing wrong with the hittesting?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code to get the position and bounds of UIElements relative to another UIElement. The code is taken from [this post](http://www.mycsharp.de/wbb2/thread.php?threadid=73929).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

public static class UIHelper
{
    public static Boolean GetUIElementCornersRelativTo(UIElement Base,
                                                UIElement RelativeTo,
                                                ref Point TopLeft,
                                                ref Point BottomLeft,
                                                ref Point BottomRight,
                                                ref Point TopRight,
                                                ref String Message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Base == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Base UIElement is null");
            }
            if (RelativeTo == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("RelativTo UIElement is null");
            }

            TopLeft = Base.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), RelativeTo);
            BottomLeft = Base.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, Base.RenderSize.Height), RelativeTo);
            BottomRight = Base.TranslatePoint(new Point(Base.RenderSize.Width, Base.RenderSize.Height), RelativeTo);
            TopRight = Base.TranslatePoint(new Point(Base.RenderSize.Width, 0), RelativeTo);

            Message = "OK";
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Message = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static Boolean GetPointRelativTo(UIElement Base,
                                     UIElement RelativeTo,
                                     Point ToProjectPoint,
                                     ref Point Result,
                                     ref String Message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Base == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Base UIElement is null");
            }
            if (RelativeTo == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("RelativTo UIElement is null");
            }

            if (ToProjectPoint == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("To project point is null");
            }

            Result = Base.TranslatePoint(ToProjectPoint, RelativeTo);

            Message = "OK";
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Message = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```